# Ruby version / Old 1.8.7 messing with a fresh RVM'ed 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, installation, rvm

I using some old server, on which is installed an old ruby 1.8.7.
For some reasons (no the best you'll tell), Ive installed rvm.

I now have apps running on this old 1.8.7, others on 1.9.3.

I can understand it is messy. I'm looking for a safe way to clean it all.
My main problem is that some gems confused on which ruby version to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can ensure that command is run in the new ruby with:

1. `rvm 1.9.3 do ...`
2. `rvm use 1.9.3; ...`
3. `source $(rvm 1.9.3 do rvm env --path); ...`

first one is good for single commands,
the last one is good for scripting.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough when it gets touchy like this. The last one seems great; my main problem is that this messy setup causes troubles on deploy mainly (otherwise with simple command line, all gems install well)

Comment: I ended up fine without rvm. Again one more thing that will do-it-all but that end up being too much.